# Why does PHP not output form data correctly?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have learned html and css and know little to nothing about php. I am trying to read the input of an HTML form using php using this code:

form.html :

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action="action.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"> <br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

action.php :

```
<?php

// getting the value of name field
$name = $_GET["name"];
// getting the value of the email field
$email = $_GET["email"];

echo "Hi, ". $name . "<br>";
echo "Your email address: ". $email ."<br>";

?>
```

When I hit submit, it shows me this:

```
"; echo "Your email address: ". $email ."
"; ?>
```

What might cause this issue?
I'm guessing I installed php wrong. I unzipped the windows php files and added their location to path.

Comment: Yeah it looks like php probably isn't set up properly. There should be an installer you can use

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be attempting to open these files directly in the browser. Php for the web needs to be ran through a web server like Apache to be processed.
There is a built in one:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php
however I'd recommend looking into WAMP. That will give you Apache (web server) MySql (database) and Php all together for Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: If you google 'php development on windows' it will give you a few other options as well